# Is there a way to please the type checker other than isinstance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing, typing

How can I check which subclass an instance belongs to, without using `isinstance`?
(My understanding is that using `isinstance` is considered bad practice?...)
For example:

```py
from typing import Protocol

class Entry(Protocol):
    name: str
    
    def is_file(self) -> bool: ...
    def is_folder(self) -> bool: ...

class File(Entry):
    name: str
    content: str

    def is_file(self) -> bool:
        return True
    def is_folder(self) -> bool:
        return False
    def get_size(self) -> int:
        return len(self.content)

class Folder(Entry):
    name: str
    children: list[Entry]
    
    def is_file(self) -> bool:
        return False
    def is_folder(self) -> bool:
        return True

def do_something(entry: Entry) -> None:
    if entry.is_file():
        print(entry.get_size())
```

On the last line of `do_something` the type checker understandably complains that `entry` has no method named `get_size`, because it obviously doesn't understand that I use `is_file` to to ensure that. (My type checker is Pylance in VSCode)
What can I do instead?
(I know this code works fine, but I would also like for it to pass type checking)

Comment: regardless of type checking, `do_something` feels too generic anyway, but FWIW using `isinstance` is not a bad practice by itself.

Comment: At least in this example, why does `do_something` accept an arbitrary `Entry` when it only operates on `File` objects?

Comment: It's not `isinstance` in particular that is frowned upon, it's runtime type checking in *any* form, in place of things like duck typing and polymorphism.

Comment: I agree with the comments above, although if this is the intended usage you could use `typing.cast(File, entry)`

Comment: Probably no need for `cast`; just use `if isinstance(entry, File):`, and the type checker will accept (via type narrowing) that `entry.get_size()` is valid.

Comment: You should re-architect your implementation to use [`functools.singledispatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch).

Comment: This is a simplified version of my code, in reality my code has no 'do_something` and instead is meant to print a folder recursively. So it loops over the children of a given folder, and if it's a file it prints that file, but if it's a folder it calls the same function on that folder. Should I edit the example code to show that?

Comment: Where exactly did you pick up that `isinstance` is bad practice? That is such a broad statement, it's just silly. I certainly have seen runtime type checking being _overused_ as alluded to by @chepner, but there is nothing inherently wrong with it. Your entire premise is very questionable. If your goal is to know the type of something, that is what `isinstance` is for. Whether or not you even _need_ to know the type is another question. Here you are just looking for custom type guards that would reinvent the `isinstance` wheel.

Comment: On an unrelated note: Inheriting from a protocol with concrete classes defeats the entire purpose of it. Protocols are explicitly meant for _structural_ subtyping, i.e. something is a subtype of it, when it complies with the protocol in its interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason *not* to use `isinstance` here. It reduces the amount of unnecessary boilerplate. It isn't `isinstance` that is frowned up, but unnecessary run-time typechecking of any kind, including your custom `is_*` methods. Assuming there is a good reason for making `do_something` so unnecessarily generic, just use the following.

```
from typing import Protocol

class Entry:
    def __init__(self, *, name: str, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.name = name
    

class File(Entry):    
    def __init__(self, *, content: str, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.content = content

    def get_size(self) -> int:
        return len(self.content)


class Folder(Entry):    
    def __init__(self, *, children: list[Entry], **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.children = children
    

def do_something(entry: Entry) -> None:
    if isinstance(entry, File):
        print(entry.get_size())
```

However, if `do_something` isn't supposed to work on anything except `File` objects, then say so in the type so you don't need any such type narrowing:

```
def do_something(entry: File) -> None:
    print(entry.get_size())
```

Answer (score 0):

A possibly more Pythonic way to handle this is to get rid of the `is_file` and `is_folder` completely.  They're nothing but `isinstance` by another name.

```
class Entry:
    def get_size(self) -> int:
        raise NotImplementedError

class File(Entry):
    ...
    def get_size(self) -> int:
        return len(self.content)

class Folder(Entry):
    ...


def do_something(entry: Entry) -> None:
    try:
        print(entry.get_size())
    except NotImplementedError:
        pass
```

Comment: This puts too much work in the base class, requiring it to anticipate every method a subclass might add.

Comment: @chepner.  I mostly agree with you.  But I don't know how this code is going to evolve.  Is OP going to add more methods? Or are they going to add more subclasses, some of which will have a sensible `get_size()` method.  I'd really like to know more about the `do_something` method . . .